# MacBook Pro M2 Max and three 5K Displays (LG Ultrafine / Apple Studio Display)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display

So far my setup was 2020 Intel MacBook Pro with 4 Thunderbolt ports, to which I had connected 3 Blackmagic eGPUs, to which 3 LG Ultrafine 5Ks were connected.

Today arrived my new 14" MacBook Pro M2 Max with macOS 13.3. I hoped to connect those 3 LG Ultrafine 5Ks out of the box. But here is the problem, I can connect only 2. The third one remains black when connecting.

Referring to [this](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT213503) Apple Support article, the third display can be connected by following these principles:

> Supports three external displays in any one of these configurations:
>
> - One display up to 6K at 60 Hz over Thunderbolt, and two displays up to 6K at 60 Hz over HDMI
> - **Two displays up to 6K at 60 Hz over Thunderbolt**, and one display up to 8K at 60 Hz (or 4K at 240 Hz) over HDMI

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

However, at the same time the specs say the following:

> Supports four external displays in this configuration:
>
> - **Three displays up to 6K at 60 Hz over Thunderbolt**, and one display up to 4K at 144 Hz over HDMI.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

From the first quote I understand: OK, I **cannot** connect 3 Thunderbolts simultanously to 5K Displays.

From the second quote I understand: I **can** safely connect 3 Thunderbolts simultanously to 5K Displays and even better, the 4th display can be connected via HDMI.

It has left me thinking, which one is true and adequate for my situation?
And maybe, have I received a faulty laptop?

What are your experiences? Anyone using triple Ultrafine 5K at their setup? Or triple Apple Studio Display?

Comment: https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro-14-and-16/specs/ says "Up to three external displays: Up to two external displays with 6K resolution at 60Hz over Thunderbolt and one external display with up to 8K resolution at 60Hz or one external display with 4K resolution at 240Hz over HDMI". Where is your "spec" quote coming from?

Comment: @nohillside has a [link](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro-14-and-16/specs/) which states *"Up to four external displays: Up to three external displays with 6K resolution at 60Hz over Thunderbolt and one external display with up to 4K resolution at 144Hz over HDMI"*. User tomasz  has a [link](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT213503) which states *"Supports four external displays in this configuration: Three displays up to 6K at 60 Hz over Thunderbolt, and one display up to 4K at 144 Hz over HDMI"*. **Both state the same specification.**

Comment: Ok, I do not think a  HDMI display this would be necessary. However, if you took the specification literally, then you would need to purchase a dummy HDMI plug. For example see [here](https://www.amazon.com/Headless-Display-Emulator-Headless-1920x1080-Generation/dp/B06XT1Z9TF). They come in all kinds of resolutions and prices.

Comment: How did you connect your monitors? - According to the specs, you need to connect the two displays via the Thunderbolt ports, and one display via the HDMI port. Did you do that?

Comment: @jksoegaard: I do not think the LG UltaFine 5K monitors have HDMI inputs. How would the monitor be connected to the Mac's HDMI port?

Comment: @DavidAnderson This was actually my point. Unless he has some special adapter in between - he's not following the specification.

Comment: You mention “faulty laptop” which implies you are attempting to connect 3 displays to your MBP M2 Max. *What cables are you using and how did you connect them? To which ports?  What were the results?*

Comment: That’s not what I asked @DavidAnderson. I would like to know how they are being connected *now*.  Read the penultimate paragraph “Maybe I received a faulty laptop?”